# Jquery disabled input and tooltipClass fail to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a basic form as I'm new to jQuery, I have made the email input require something to be inputted for the submit button to become active:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        validate();
        $('#email').change(validate);
    });

    function validate(){
        if ($('#email').val().length   >   0 ) {
            $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
            $("input[type=submit]").tooltip({ disabled: true });
        }
        else {
            $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    $( "input[type=submit]" ).tooltip({ tooltipClass: "tooltip" },{ position: { my: "left center", at: "right center" } });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works fine but my tooltipClass that I have doesn't work on the submit, only the #email element i have, If I remove the above script it works fine.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $( '#email' ).tooltip({ tooltipClass: "tooltip" },{ position: { my: "left center", at: "right center" } });
    $( '#submit' ).tooltip({ tooltipClass: "tooltip" },{ position: { my: "left center", at: "right center" } });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A fiddle is greatly appreciated

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: could you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo, which could actually reproduce the issue?

Comment: sorry never used it before, I've put it in but it's not working, hopefully something stupid I've done - http://jsfiddle.net/yHJ3Z/